# Jquery parents() help

Tags: jquery

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work? I'm trying to show and hide content.

Here is my markup

```
<div class="entry">
  <p class="posted">
    test<br />
    <a href="#" class="toggle" title="Show Comments">
      Show/Hide
    </a>
  </p>
  <div class="box" class="comment">
    test hidden comment
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
$(function () {
  $('div.box').hide();
  $('a.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.entry').next('div.box').toggle(400);
  });
});
```

The way this example sits right now, If I take the last closing div and move it up after the closing p tag, it works fine but shows and hides **all** hidden content (divs) which is not what I'm after. I'd only like to show the content that is associated with each link.

Comment: Did you register twice to ask the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620149/is-there-a-way-to-make-this-jquery-script-dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use .parent instead of .parents.

this will work:

```
    $(function() {
        $('div.box').hide();
        $('a.toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).parent('.posted').next('div.box').toggle(400);
        });
    });
```

Comment: element 'div.box' is not sibling to 'div.entry'. it should be 'p.posted'

Comment: Hey Q8, yes, that did work. Thanks! One more small issue that I have no idea as to why... but when I click the test link, the browser opens the hidden content and at the same time, pushes / scrolls the content up. The same behavior as when a user click the common "Top" link to go back to the top of the page. Would you know why?

Comment: You can use .parents() as well.  .parents() looks farther back into the DOM than .parent(), which only gets the immediate parent.  `.parents('div.entry').children('div.box')` does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Q8. Even though the boxes are opening just fine now, the page scrolls up when the link to the hidden content is pressed. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: is the test link/ 'top' link use 'toggle' as class? you should ask a new question. and show your markup/script for that case.

Comment: Well, that's the thing.. I'm not using a top link but jquery needs the "#" in the a tag.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I do have another image that will take the user to the bottom of the page where the comments box is but the page jumps up, not down.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the `parents` that's the problem, it's the `next()`.  `next()` fetches sibling elements, whereas you need the nested sub-elements.  Use `children()` instead.  Try this, it worked for me:

```
$(function () {
  $('div.box').hide();
  $('a.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.entry').children('div.box').toggle(400);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Zombat. I made the changes and your solution also works. I'm also having an issue where when the link is clicked to open and close the box, the page jumps to the top. Would you know why this is?

Comment: Hi Jack, yes, it's because you have the `href` of the link equal to `#`.  This is the syntax for a named anchor, and if no name is given after the `#`, the browser just goes to the top of the page.  Change your link to `href="javascript:void(0)"` and it won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
class="comment" overrides class="box", use class="comment box"
```

Comment: Hi Parkim, are you referring to the issue I am having with the page jumping up to the top? I tried this but it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you change `next()` to `find()` or `children()`:

```
$(function () {
  $('div.box').hide();
  $('a.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.entry').find('div.box').toggle(400);
  });
});
```

This is because `next()` gets the siblings of the object, while `find()` searches the descendants.  When your code calls `next()` the object is `'.entry'` which has no siblings, you can use `children()` as zombat suggests or `find()` as I have done to locate `div.box` as it is a descendant of `'.entry'`.

Comment: Thanks Beggs. Can I ask.. What exactly is it doing? I mean, the parent tag.. What is its function and when it finds the elements, how do I access them?

Comment: What id does:
 `$('a.toggle').click(...`: this means add an "onClick()" method to all elements of type 'a' with class 'toggle'
 `function() { $(this).parents('.entry').find('div.box').toggle(400); }`: anonymous function assigned to the click event saying "take the element that was clicked and find all the ancestors (`parents()`) take any ancestors with class `.entry` and find any of it's descendants with type 'div' and class 'box' and call `toggle()` on that element.

If you used `next()` the function would be on a *sibling* of `.entry1 an element at the same level of the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Parkim, are you referring to the
>   issue I am having with the page
>   jumping up to the top? I tried this
>   but it still does the same thing. –
>   Jack

nope, because of override, you can't use ".box" selector.
you page jumps to the top, because of "#" anchor, you should use "return false" to prevent default "click" handler.

```
$( "a" ).click( function() { /* your code */ return false; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, I'd use `closest` and `find` instead of `parent` and `children` respectively, I think it's more a matter of preference though.

```
$(function () {
  $('div.box').hide();
  $('a.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.entry').find('div.box').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});
```